# Ansible concat vars to string

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I've spent most of the day trying to solve this problem and have thus far failed. I am building some playbooks to automate functions in Splunk, and am attempting to convert a list of hosts from an inventory group E.G.

```
[search_head]
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
```

My expected (desired) result from the debug output of the play should be:
`https://1.2.3.4:8089, https://5.6.7.8:8089`

I am attempting to complete this by running the following playbook against a running host:

```
---
  - name: Build search head list to initialize the captain
    hosts: search_head
    remote_user: ansible
    vars:
      inventory_file: ./inventory-ec2-single-site
      search_head_uri: "{{ lookup('template', './bootstrap-sh-deployer.j2') }}"
pre_tasks:
  - include_vars: 
      dir: 'group_vars'
      extensions:
        - yml
        - yaml
tasks:
  - name: dump array
    debug:
        msg: "{{ search_head_uri }}"`
```

With the template `bootstrap-sh-deployer.j2`:

```
{%- set search_head_uri = [] %}
{% for host in groups['search_head'] %}
    {%- if search_head_uri.append("https://{{ host }}:8089") %} 
{%- endif %}
{%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
{%- endfor %}
```

However, the current play returns `search_head_uri: ", "` which tells me that the loop is running, but `{{ host }}` is not resolving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you open a Jinja2 expression or a statement you should use Jinja2 syntax. You cannot nest them (i.e. you can't use `{{ }}` inside `{% %}`).

```
{%- if search_head_uri.append("https://" + host + ":8089") %}
```

Comment: Awesome, it stopped erroring out. Now I'm trying to get the `ansible_nodename` from each host in the `inventory` file.

    `{%- set search_head_uri = [true] %}
    {% for host in groups['search_head'] %}
        {%- if search_head_uri.append("https://" + [host][ansible_nodename] + ":8089") %}
        {% endif -%}
        {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
    {%- endfor %}`

Comment: Errors with: 
`fatal: [1.2.3.4]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: {{ lookup('template', './bootstrap-sh-deployer.j2') }}: 'list object' has no attribute u'ip-1-2-3-4'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Users/christophergarrett/dev/splunk-ansible/deploy_ec2_testing.yml': line 16, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    tasks:\n      - name: dump array\n        ^ here\n"
}`

Comment: If you have a different problem, please post a different question. Before, think about the reason why you enclosed `host` in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This worked - Combination of the answer above to fix jinja formatting and using `hostvars` to get to the `ansible_nodename`.

```
{%- set search_head_uri = [] %}
{% for host in groups['search_head'] %}
    {{ "https://" + hostvars[host]['ansible_nodename'] + ":8089" }}
    {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
{%- endfor %}
```